# How can I disable specific select options if given condition is true?

Tags: reactjs, select, antd

I am using ant design select field with options of months. I have an array of 12 months of a year and I am mapping it through and displaying it as dropdown selectable options. I want to disable all previous months before present month. For example, If present month is October, I want to disable all of previous months before October, so user won't be able to select those months. [This is how it looks like on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjccC.png) and below is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const monthData = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];

<Select
getPopupContainer={(trigger) =>  return trigger}}
autoClearSearchValue={true}
bordered={false}
showSearch
placeholder="Select Month"
optionFilterProp="children"
>
{monthData.map((month) => (<Option value={month} {/*disabled = {}*/}>{month}</Option>))}
</Select>
```

Comment: Do you have any variable that holds current month?

Comment: No, I don't have it. @MrBens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the index of current month using built-in `Date`:

```
const currentMonthIndex = new Date().getMonth();
```

Now you can enable/disable the `Option` components using `map`:

```
{monthData.map((month, index) => (<Option value={month} disabled={index < currentMonthIndex}>{month}</Option>))}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your solution but it has disabled all of options. Please have a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-moser-jnkf3u?file=/src/App.js @MrBens

Comment: It works fine if I do it like this: disabled = {index < currentMonthIndex}. Thanks alot for your help. For anyone else looking for answer, here's working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-moser-jnkf3u?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You right, my mistake. I fixed it in the answer.